# Can't initialize the state of the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm sure i have initialized the state of my redux store ,however, i always get undefined

initialized the state in a const then the reducer then the store. and i did console.log(store) because i get undefined when i provide the store to the app

````
const init = {
    counter:0
};

//reducer
const mainReducer= (state=init, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INC_COUNTER':
        return {...state, counter:state.counter+1}
        case 'de':
        return {counter:-1}
    }
}

const Appstore = Redux.createStore(mainReducer);


console.log("this is your current state",Appstore.getState())```
````

Comment: add `default` clause to your switch statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be returning a default state. Note that the redux stores will be initiliazed with an INIT action, in this case, you will return undefined, cause the action type will neither be INC_COUNTER or de

you should always handle a default case like

```
const mainReducer= (state=init, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INC_COUNTER':
        return {...state, counter:state.counter+1}
        case 'de':
        return {counter:-1}
    }
    return state;
}
```